# Elasticsearch - Highlight not working on attachments

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have indexed some attachments into my Elasticsearch database. When I make a full text search with words in the attachment, I get the result back(hits), but I do not get "highlight" in the response.

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong, here is my code:

```
    [ElasticsearchType(Name = "temporaryapplication")]
public class Attachment
{
    [String(Name = "_content", Store = true, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
public class Document
{
    [Attachment]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am making a search request:

```
    public async Task<StructuredSearchResponse> GetApplications(Guid positionId, SearchQuery query)
    {
        var searchResult =
            await _client.LowLevel.SearchAsync<string>(ApplicationsIndexName, "temporaryapplication", new SearchRequest()
            {
                From = (query.PageSize*query.PageNumber) - query.PageSize,
                Size = query.PageSize,
                Query = GetQuery(query),
                Source = GetFields(),
                Aggregations = GetAggregations(),
                Highlight = new Highlight() {
                    Fields = new Dictionary<Field, IHighlightField>
                    {
                        { "file.content", new HighlightField
                            {
                                Type = HighlighterType.Postings,
                                HighlightQuery = new MatchQuery
                                {
                                    Field = "file.content",
                                    Query = query.Freetext
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            });

        return searchResult.ToStructuredSearchResponse(query.PageSize, query.PageNumber);
    }
```

The index mapping:

```
                var indexDescriptor =
                new CreateIndexDescriptor(new IndexName {Name = ApplicationsIndexName}).Mappings(
                    ms => ms.Map<TemporaryApplication>(m => m.AutoMap())
                        .Map<Attachment>(m => m.AutoMap()));


            _client.CreateIndex(indexDescriptor);
```

The POCO for mapping:

```
public class TemporaryApplication
{
    [String(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "Education")]
    public string Education { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "WorkExperience")]
    public string WorkExperience { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Attachment]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }
}
```

Method for indexing attachment:

```
    public async void IndexDocument(Attachment attachmentDocument)
    {
        var doc = new Document()
        {
            File = attachmentDocument,
        };

        var updateResponse = _client.Update<TemporaryApplication, object>(5, descriptor => descriptor
        .Doc(new { file = doc.File }));
    }
```

JSON for document:

```
   {
   "_index": "applications",
   "_type": "temporaryapplication",
   "_id": "5",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
     "_source": {
          "FirstName": "Petter",
          "LastName": "Stordalen",
          "Education": "master",
          "WorkExperience": "3years",
          "Age": "8.0",
          "Id": 5,
          "file": {
               "_name": "07443a5a-ad56-4610-bd53-8b8ea43a4c89 (1).doc",
                "_content_type": "application/msword",
                "_content":
                "e1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNwZzEyNTJcZGVmZjBcbm91aWNvbXBhdFxkZWZsYW5nMTA0NHtcZm9udHRibHtcZjBcZm5pbFxmY2hhcnNldDAgQ2FsaWJyaTt9fQ0Ke1wqXGdlbmVyYXRvciBSaWNoZWQyMCAxMC4wLjE0MzkzfVx2aWV3a2luZDRcdWMxIA0KXHBhcmRcc2EyMDBcc2wyNzZcc2xtdWx0MVxmMFxmczIyXGxhbmcyMCBWQ1hDVlhDVlhDVlhDVlhWWENWWENWXHBhcg0KfQ0KAA=="
        }
    }
   }
```

JSON for mapping: 
[Elasticsearch mapping updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITzcw.png)
GetQuery Method:

```
public static class ElasticsearchExtensions
{
    public static StructuredSearchResponse ToStructuredSearchResponse(this ElasticsearchResponse<string> response, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
    {
        return new StructuredSearchResponse(JObject.Parse(response.Body), pageSize,pageNumber);
    }

    public static QueryContainer AddEducation(this QueryContainer queryContainer, SearchQuery query)
    {
        if (query.Education.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < query.Education.Count; i++)
            {
                queryContainer |= new MatchQuery()
                {
                    Field = "Education",
                    Query = query.Education[i]
                };
            }
        }
        return queryContainer;
    }

    public static QueryContainer AddWorkExperience(this QueryContainer queryContainer, SearchQuery query)
    {
        if (query.WorkExperience.Count > 0)
        {
            if (queryContainer != null)
            {
                queryContainer &= new MatchQuery()
                {
                    Field = "WorkExperience",
                    Query = query.WorkExperience[0]
                };

                for (var i = 1; i < query.WorkExperience.Count; i++)
                {
                    queryContainer |= new MatchQuery()
                    {
                        Field = "WorkExperience",
                        Query = query.WorkExperience[i]
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < query.WorkExperience.Count; i++)
                {
                    queryContainer |= new MatchQuery()
                    {
                        Field = "WorkExperience",
                        Query = query.WorkExperience[i]
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        return queryContainer;
    }

    public static QueryContainer AddAgeInterval(this QueryContainer queryContainer, SearchQuery query)
    {
        if (query.FromAge != "" || query.ToAge != "")
        {
            dynamic From = null;
            dynamic To = null;

            if (query.FromAge != null)
            {
                From = Convert.ToDouble(query.FromAge);
            }

            if (query.ToAge != null)
            {
                To = Convert.ToDouble(query.ToAge);
            }

            if (queryContainer == null)
            {
                queryContainer = new NumericRangeQuery()
                {
                    Field = "Age",
                    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = From,
                    LessThanOrEqualTo = To,
                };
            }
            else
            {
                queryContainer &= new NumericRangeQuery()
                {
                    Field = "Age",
                    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = From,
                    LessThanOrEqualTo = To
                };
            }
        }

        return queryContainer;
    }

    public static QueryContainer AddFreeTextSearch(this QueryContainer queryContainer, SearchQuery query)
    {
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Freetext)))
        {
            if (queryContainer == null)
            {
                queryContainer |= new QueryStringQuery()
                {
                    Fields =
                        Field.Create("FirstName").And("LastName").And("Education").And("WorkExperience").And("Age").And("file.content"),
                    Query = "*" + query.Freetext + "*"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                queryContainer &= new QueryStringQuery() 
                {
                    Fields =
                        Field.Create("FirstName").And("LastName").And("Education").And("WorkExperience").And("Age").And("file.content"),
                    Query = "*" + query.Freetext + "*"
                };
            }
        }
        return queryContainer;
    }
}
```

}

This is what query parameter contains:

[Query Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRYHt.png)

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments#highlighting-attachments) your mapping is wrong

> If you want to highlight your attachment content, you will need to set
>   "store": true and "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets" for your
>   attachment field. Here is a full script which does it:

I see that you have all of that in code, so maybe you have added it after index was created. Try to drop and recreate it

It [seems that Nest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1276#issuecomment-83736166) is not able to map complex type

```
  var indexDescriptor =
                new CreateIndexDescriptor(new IndexName {Name = ApplicationsIndexName}).Mappings(
                    ms => ms.Map<TemporaryApplication>(m => m.AutoMap())
                        .Map<Attachment>(m => m.AutoMap()
                        .Properties(ps => ps
      .Attachment(s => s.Name(p => p.File)
        .FileField(ff => ff.Name(p => p.File).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
      )
    )));
```

Comment: But I am doing it in the attachment model class

Comment: @JagjitSingh Yes but have you done it from very beginning? So what i would do i would write method like Init index, then dropped old one and use init, then before indexing check if you have right settings.

Comment: I have changed the index mapping, no it will automap attachment to, do you think it will solve the problem?

Comment: Yes because for higlights there should be kind of metadata, and you must enable it in mappings.

Comment: @JagjitSingh If you see right mapping then for sure it will work :)

Comment: The problem is I dont have the right mapping.  If you take look at my TemporaryApplication.cs class, I have only provided [Attachment] type, not term_vector and with_positions_offsets. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @JagjitSingh you can always do mapping manually https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html

Comment: Not possible to get the same result with auto mapping?